# How to disable specific parts of an application in jsf?

Tags: java, jsf, servlets

I have a JSF application in which I have different servlets and facelets. The server is on real IP. Now what I want is that, one servlet be accessible from anywhere online, rest of the application should be only accessible via localhost? What's the easiest way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `Filter` which is mapped on an `url-pattern` covering the resources you'd like to hide and does basically as follows in `doFilter()` method:

```
if (request.getRemoteAddr().equals(request.getLocalAddr())) {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
} else {
    ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
}
```

It'll show a [HTTP 403 `FORBIDDEN`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.4) error for requests not originated by same client as where the server runs.